# Can anyone specify what kind of function can be used in this case?

Tags: functions, mathematical-modeling, curves

I have some data as shown in the figure, and I just want to collapse all the 4 curves into a single curve.

The 4 curves correspond to 4 different values $a$ mentioned in the legend.

I think the best way may be is to multiply the $y$ values with an expression which is a function of both $a$ and $x$ to get $y = 1$ in all the 4 curves.

For this, I can multiply the purple and green curves with something like $(1/a)^{f(x)}$. But this function is proving good for the purple curve and not the green one.

Moreover, when I use this for the blue and red curves too, their values shoot up a lot.

So I am thinking how best to collapse the curves using a single function, $f(a,x)$ which on multiplying with the purple and green curves give 1, and on multiplying with the red and blue curves do not change its value.

I tried some exponential functions, but I am not quite getting any success.

Any solution to this or advice?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Except for a=0.25,
all the curves 
look pretty linear.
You might try
a standard linear least squares fit
of each data set
to get
y = mx+b
and see what
m and b look like 
as functions of a.

Do you have a model 
of what the curves should look like?
If you do,
I think you should
try to fit that type of curve
to each data set.